# How do I get ruby to print a full backtrace instead of a truncated one?

Tags: ruby, exception, stack-trace

When I get exceptions, it is often from deep within the call stack.  When this happens, more often than not, the actual offending line of code is hidden from me:

```
tmp.rb:7:in `t': undefined method `bar' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from tmp.rb:10:in `s'
        from tmp.rb:13:in `r'
        from tmp.rb:16:in `q'
        from tmp.rb:19:in `p'
        from tmp.rb:22:in `o'
        from tmp.rb:25:in `n'
        from tmp.rb:28:in `m'
        from tmp.rb:31:in `l'
         ... 8 levels...
        from tmp.rb:58:in `c'
        from tmp.rb:61:in `b'
        from tmp.rb:64:in `a'
        from tmp.rb:67
```

That "... 8 levels..." truncation is causing me a great deal of trouble.  I'm not having much success googling for this one:  How do I tell ruby that I want dumps to include the full stack?

Comment: Is there a way to do this from the command line instead?

Answer (score 306, accepted):

Exception#backtrace has the entire stack in it:

```
def do_division_by_zero; 5 / 0; end
begin
  do_division_by_zero
rescue => exception
  puts exception.backtrace
  raise # always reraise
end
```

(Inspired by Peter Cooper's [Ruby Inside](http://www.rubyinside.com/21-ruby-tricks-902.html) blog)

Comment: I'd reraise the exception, at least for the sake of the examples completness.

Comment: To reraise you just need to say `raise`. No need to explicitly specify the execption you want to raise.

Comment: Nice, I always thought you had to pass the previous exception to raise.  I didn't realize that it defaults to the last exception rescued.

Comment: What if your code doesn't throw an exception, you just want to see the stack trace of where it went?

Comment: the problem with this and other solutions is that we don't know which file threw the exception in the first place. This is a catch 22 situation. In order to get the full st we need to add this code. But in order to add this code we must know where the error is coming from which we can only know if we get the full st.

Answer (score 220):

You could also do this if you'd like a simple one-liner:

```
puts caller
```

Comment: Awesome trick. Thanks a lot. I didn't know that `raise` can be used with no arguments. Neither I knew that `rescue` will be treated correctly as one-liner. I also totally ignore those global vars like `$!`.

Comment: no need to raise/rescue, you can just use Kernel#caller, like so:
`puts "this line was reached by #{caller.join("\n")}"`

Comment: Ah, I found out about that shortly after posting this answer and forgot to update it. Thanks

Comment: I use `y caller` to print the output like Java stack trace.

Comment: `caller(0,2)` would return the two latest entries in the stacktrace. Nice for outputting abbreviated stacktraces.

Comment: However, using `caller` instead of `e.backtrace` in a rake task's error handling step (a `rescue` block) won't give you the stacktrace of the models being called, just the stacktrace of the rake task, so that was quite useless..

Comment: This answer is not for the OP's stated use case because it shows the currect position in the code rather than where the exception occurred.

Answer (score 110):

This produces the error description and nice clean, indented stacktrace:

```
begin               
 # Some exception throwing code
rescue => e
  puts "Error during processing: #{$!}"
  puts "Backtrace:\n\t#{e.backtrace.join("\n\t")}"
end
```

Answer (score 57):

IRB has a setting for this awful "feature", which you can customize.

Create a file called `~/.irbrc` that includes the following line:

```
IRB.conf[:BACK_TRACE_LIMIT] = 100
```

This will allow you to see 100 stack frames in `irb`, at least. I haven't been able to find an equivalent setting for the non-interactive runtime.

Detailed information about IRB customization can be found in the [Pickaxe book](http://www.rubycentral.com/book/irb.html).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it addresses the question of how to show more of the backtrace instead of "...X levels..." .

Comment: Pickaxe link is now broken.

Answer (score 18):

One liner for callstack:

```
begin; Whatever.you.want; rescue => e; puts e.message; puts; puts e.backtrace; end
```

One liner for callstack without all the gems's:

```
begin; Whatever.you.want; rescue => e; puts e.message; puts; puts e.backtrace.grep_v(/\/gems\//); end
```

One liner for callstack without all the gems's and relative to current directory

```
begin; Whatever.you.want; rescue => e; puts e.message; puts; puts e.backtrace.grep_v(/\/gems\//).map { |l| l.gsub(`pwd`.strip + '/', '') }; end
```

Comment: one-liner is actually a bad thing when you have multiple statements.

Comment: @nurettin this is for quick debugging purpose so making it one line makes it easy to copy paste it, mostly in interactive shells

Comment: @Dorian You remind me about a question that I had: "Why are interactive shells useful? (excluding Shell-script)".

Answer (score 12):

This mimics the official Ruby trace, if that's important to you.

```
begin
  0/0  # or some other nonsense
rescue => e
  puts e.backtrace.join("\n\t")
       .sub("\n\t", ": #{e}#{e.class ? " (#{e.class})" : ''}\n\t")
end
```

Amusingly, it doesn't handle 'unhandled exception' properly, reporting it as 'RuntimeError', but the location is correct.

Comment: I regret that I have but one upvote to give for your answer. I add this everywhere

Answer (score 5):

Almost everybody answered this. My version of printing any rails exception into logs would be:

```
begin
    some_statement
rescue => e
    puts "Exception Occurred #{e}. Message: #{e.message}. Backtrace:  \n #{e.backtrace.join("\n")}"
    Rails.logger.error "Exception Occurred #{e}. Message: #{e.message}. Backtrace:  \n #{e.backtrace.join("\n")}"
end
```

Comment: This is a nice clear and simple template, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I was getting these errors when trying to load my test environment (via rake test or autotest) and the IRB suggestions didn't help.  I ended up wrapping my entire test/test_helper.rb in a begin/rescue block and that fixed things up.

```
begin
  class ActiveSupport::TestCase
    #awesome stuff
  end
rescue => e
  puts e.backtrace
end
```

Answer (score 1):

**[examine all threads backtraces to find the culprit]**
Even fully expanded call stack can still hide the actual offending line of code from you when you use more than one thread!

Example: One thread is iterating ruby Hash, other thread is trying to modify it. BOOM! Exception! And the problem with the stack trace you get while trying to modify 'busy' hash is that it shows you chain of functions down to the place where you're trying to modify hash, but it does NOT show who's currently iterating it in parallel (who owns it)! Here's the way to figure that out by printing stack trace for ALL currently running threads. Here's how you do this:

```
# This solution was found in comment by @thedarkone on https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24627
rescue Object => boom

    thread_count = 0
    Thread.list.each do |t|
      thread_count += 1
      err_msg += "--- thread #{thread_count} of total #{Thread.list.size} #{t.object_id} backtrace begin \n"
      # Lets see if we are able to pin down the culprit
      # by collecting backtrace for all existing threads:
      err_msg += t.backtrace.join("\n")
      err_msg += "\n---thread #{thread_count} of total #{Thread.list.size} #{t.object_id} backtrace end \n"
    end

    # and just print it somewhere you like:
    $stderr.puts(err_msg)

    raise # always reraise
end
```

The above code snippet is useful even just for educational purposes as it can show you (like x-ray) how many threads you actually have (versus how many you thought you have - quite often those two are different numbers ;)

Answer (score -2):

You can also use [backtrace](https://github.com/yegor256/backtrace) Ruby gem (I'm the author):

```
require 'backtrace'
begin
  # do something dangerous
rescue StandardError => e
  puts Backtrace.new(e)
end
```

Comment: Can you at least explain why we'd want to use your gem? Can you show some sample output?

Comment: @ioquatix the output is almost exactly the same as you would get with `e.backtrace.join("\n\t")`, but with my gem your Ruby code will look shorter and nicer, and will have no duplication (everywhere you need to print stacktraces)