# Get stacktrace classes, not just files, in Ruby

Tags: ruby

My goal is to find if the current stack has `ActionJob::Base` in it to see if it came from a background job.

I figure the way to do that is calling classes for my current location in ruby so I can search and find `ActionJob::Base` ancestor class in the call stack.

There are [a few ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7724200/399632) to get a stacktrace/backtrace from [the current location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122233/get-current-stack-trace-in-ruby-without-raising-an-exception) in ruby. They involve `Thread.current.backtrace`. That results in an array of strings as filenames but not classes that were called. i.e.

```
/Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:537:in `eval_input'
/Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:472:in `block in run'
/Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:471:in `catch'
/Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:471:in `run'
/Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:400:in `start'
/Users/justin/dev/testarea/lamby_discovery/vendor/bundle-dev/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:70:in `start'
/Users/justin/dev/testarea/lamby_discovery/vendor/bundle-dev/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:19:in `start'
/Users/justin/dev/testarea/lamby_discovery/vendor/bundle-dev/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:102:in `perform'
/Users/justin/dev/testarea/lamby_discovery/vendor/bundle-dev/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/Users/justin/dev/testarea/lamby_discovery/vendor/bundle-dev/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
/Users/justin/dev/testarea/lamby_discovery/vendor/bundle-dev/ruby/2.7.0/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
/Users/justin/dev/testarea/lamby_discovery/vendor/bundle-dev/ruby/2.7.0/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
```

byebug's `backtrace` has the information that I'm looking for (i.e. `IRB::Context`), but doesn't seem searchable and `backtrace` is a c method.

```
--> #0  IRB::Context.set_last_value(value#NilClass) at /Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/context.rb:363
    #1  IRB::Context.evaluate(line#String, line_no#Integer, exception#NilClass) at /Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/context.rb:459
    #2  block (2 levels) in IRB::Irb.block (2 levels) in eval_input at /Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:541
    #3  IRB::Irb.signal_status(status#Symbol) at /Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:704
    #4  block in IRB::Irb.block in eval_input at /Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:538
    #5  block (2 levels) in RubyLex.block (2 levels) in each_top_level_statement at /Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:166
    ͱ-- #6  Kernel.loop at /Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:151
    #7  block in RubyLex.block in each_top_level_statement at /Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:151
    ͱ-- #8  Kernel.catch(*args) at /Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:150
    #9  RubyLex.each_top_level_statement at /Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb/ruby-lex.rb:150
    #10 IRB::Irb.eval_input at /Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:537
    #11 block in IRB::Irb.block in run(conf#Hash) at /Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:472
    ͱ-- #12 Kernel.catch(*args) at /Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:471
    #13 IRB::Irb.run(conf#Hash) at /Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:471
    #14 #<Class:IRB>.start(ap_path#NilClass) at /Users/justin/.rbenv/versions/2.7.3/lib/ruby/2.7.0/irb.rb:400
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: Another option would be to set a `Thread.current` variable in ActionJob's [`before_perform`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html), then you could check for this variable's existence to know if it's in a background job

Comment: @maxpleaner that's a good idea. I'll probably end up using it given the any solution involving reading the stack for classes doesn't seem realistic.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is loop through `caller` (you can limit, eg. `caller.first(10)`), and each of them, i'll load source code then check whether source string `include?` the target class or not (eg. `ActionJob::Base`).

Here is my solution, i use [gem solargraph](https://github.com/castwide/solargraph) which help to parse source code (parse `namspace`, `constants`, `methods`, ...), in your case, we need to find any caller class has `superclass` is `ActionJob::Base`, right ? Solargraph support we do it:

```
gem 'solargraph', group: :development
bundle install

# debug helper
class Debug
  def self.search_super(caller, super_clazz)
    detect_paths = []
    caller.each do |caller_path|
      unless caller_path.nil?
        filepath = caller_path.split(':').first
        source = Solargraph::Source.load_string(File.read(filepath), filepath)
        map = Solargraph::SourceMap.map(source)
        detect = map.pins_by_class(Solargraph::Pin::Reference::Superclass)
        .select { |clazz| 
          clazz.to_s == super_clazz.to_s
        }
        unless detect.blank?
          detect_paths << filepath
        end
      end
    end
    detect_paths
  end
end
```

then for example, you want to detect which job call the method `Demo#search`, you can set a break point on that method

```rb
class Demo
  def search
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

and check in console

```sh
> Debug.search_super(caller, "ActionJob::Base")
```

**note** I tested on myside to detect superclass "ActionController::Base" (rails) and it worked, but i've not tested for ActionJobs yet.

Comment: Wow this is very impressive. Sorry, I should have clarified... I'm looking to use this in production and running Solargraph in prod isn't something I should be doing. But because the solution is so complex, I'm assuming it's not really possible given the stdlibs.